# How to override default values of form on submit event

Tags: drupal

I have a form which has textfields with default values specified. On submit event, I want these default values to be changed with the new set of values that I am passing. I am using form_set_value($element, $value, $form_state) for this. However it is  not updating. Any ideas? My code is

```
 function sample_myform($form_state){

$form['field']['name'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title'=> 'Name: ',
'#maxlength'=> 127,
   '#default_value' => param1,
);
   $form['field']['placeholder'] = array(
  '#type'=> 'value',
  '#value' => array(),
   );
$form['field']['button1'] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#value' => 'Submit',
);
return $form;
   }

  function sample_myform_validate($form,&$form_state){


$name2 = $form_state['values']['name'];
   form_set_value($form['field']['placeholder'], $name2, $form_state); */
form_set_value($form['field']['name'],'God',$form_state);
$form_state['rebuild'] = true;
 }
```

Comment: try to pass $form_state as reference sample_myform(&$form_state) and see what happen :)

Comment: I passed the sample_myform(&$form_state) . But the default value still persists :(

Answer (score 0):

One thing for sure, $form['field']['placeholder'] will never, ever change since you set #value. Once #value is set, Form API moves on. Be careful though with setting just #default_value on a #type value as that can be tampered with. You can do something like $form_state['placeholder'] = $name2; in validate and use that in the form builder function.

What you try to do with name works in Drupal 7 but I suspect you are in Drupal 6. The validate function overwrites $form_state['values'] just fine but that's not persisted for the form rebuild. Once again, save into $form_state as you need.